# Converting a resultset variable to an array

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS (VS 2008) and I want to take a populated resultset variable (populated from an EXECUTE SQL task) and convert within an SSIS Script Component (c#) it into an array.

The resultset contains a single column.

What would be the code to do this?

**Edit**: This is for a backfilling exercise; in normal circumstances, a web app calls a proc on the db that passes in a text string and gets a list of matching words based on this kind of query:

```
SELECT  [Term] 
    FROM    [dbo].[ATableOFTerms] WITH ( NOLOCK )    
    WHERE   CHARINDEX(' ' + Term + ' ', @StringBeingSearched) > 0
```

Once the web app gets this list, it has a lot of business rules around what it converts it to but essentially it takes the list of matching terms and generates a single string that is then used for passing into a fulltext search.

The backfilling process in SSIS needs to mimic that so the script component has the same web app code that deals with the business logic but I needed c# code that does the above. Which is fine, I am returning all the [ATableTerms] into a resultset variable but now I need populate an array from the variable.

When I have this I can use string.Contains to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexOf(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0This is how it was solved, although I'd love to get an alternative to this.

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

string Title = " " + Row.Title + " ";           
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt , Variables.ATableOfTerms);


ArrayList terms = new ArrayList();
ArrayList returnedTerms = new ArrayList();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    terms.Add(" " + dr["Term"] + " ");

}


foreach (string term in terms)
{
    if (Title.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        returnedTerms.Add(term.Trim());

    }
}
```

Comment: The only other thing I had to do was make the terms ArrayList static otherwise it would only work once.. (first row).